# Why this code (pseudocode) with semaphores use three semaphores instead of 2?

Tags: java, algorithm, semaphore

[Pseudocode with Semaphores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty1WE.png)

Hello, in our Java-course at our university we learn at the moment something about Semaphores.Our prof showed us code with only one semaphore. After this he said: "now I will you show a pseudocode with semaphores and synchronisation"...

That, what he showed us i uploaded here.

What I dont understand why we need now 3 semaphores, why he doesnt do this:

```
semaphore mutex=0;
semaphore kx=1;

void producer{

down(kx);
insert_item(item);
up(mutex);


}

void consumer{

down(mutex);
item=remove_item();
up(kx);
consume_item(item)

}
```

This is the same or not? With only two semaphores? What he means with synchronisation?

Comment: What you have posted is subject to something called **deadlock**. The *dead* should be a hint as to why you might want to avoid changing lock orders like that.

Comment: No I dont have a deadlock, because semaphore kx is initialized with 1 and mutex with 0, so of course consumer cannot start, but producer cans start and use his method. after this he makes mutex up and consumer cans start, with down mutex and producer waits until consumer ups kx, and starts again, so never a deadlock.

Comment: Or do you mean that i have avoided a deadlock with my code and that was the prof made is something else?

Comment: Why don't you ask your prof directly? What he meant and why he's doing it like that can best be explained by himself.

Comment: The `mutex` allows only one thread to produce or consume an element at a time. Or, more specifically, it only allows one thread to modify the data structure at a time. The `full` and `empty` semaphores are used to control "capacity". As in, it prevents the data structure from containing more than `N` elements or less than `0` elements. Notice the order these semaphores are used. If the data structure is empty or full, then the thread waits until the data structure is not empty or not full before it acquires the mutex.

Comment: Your code does not prevent multiple threads from modifying the data structure simultaneously. Well, it might, because your capacity is effectively `1`. But if you increased the maximum capacity to `2` or more, then that's where you'd run into problems.

Comment: Thank you Slaw! You are completely right!